# DC Motor not responding to GPIO Motor

Tags: gpio, dc-motor, gpiozero

I want to control 4 DC Motors from a Raspberry Pi. I am just starting by making sure that 1 motor can be controlled. I am following this guide: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/14, which explains the wiring configuration for the motor control board to the motor, and how to use the Motor class in the gpiozero library.

I have connected the Motor Control Board powered by dual H-bridge IC L293D http://shop.sb-components.co.uk/products/motorshield-for-raspberry-pi to the Raspberry Pi, and the battery box to the motor control board (switched on). When directly connecting my DC motor to the battery box, the motor spins very fast, so I know that it works. The motor has 2 wires (black and red) which I connect to the holes for Motor 1 on the motor control board as follows:

[image]

I am also following the pin documentation for the motor control board:

[image]

After everything is connected, I run the following code on the Raspberry Pi (using user Vadim's suggestion):

```
from gpiozero import Motor

motor1 = Motor(forward=15, backward=13, enable=11)

while True:
    motor1.forward()
```

However, the motor does not move at all. I was a bit confused by the pin description, as I am not sure what the distinction between 'enable' and 'control' is, as they have a total of 3 GPIO pins (11, 13, and 15), but I have only 2 wires on my motor.

However, I have tried every combination of GPIO values into my code above: Motor(11, 15, 13), Motor(15, 11, 13), Motor(13, 11, 15), etc. None of them get the motor to move. Am I missing something? Should I be directly connecting the motor wires to the pins of the motor controller board? Or something else?

Comment: If you want help put details of what YOU did in your question. Don't expect everyone to follow a link and guess what you did. I read the tutorial but it is unclear (at least to me).

Comment: After the link of the tutorial (which I just included in case anyone wanted a reference), I explained exactly how I wired my motor to the motor control board. Then I explained what I included in my code, and everything that I tried.

Comment: The link to the Motorshield for the Raspberry Pi fails to provide any pin details or describe how to connect. WHAT have to ACTUALLY connected?

Comment: You have hinted at the connections.  We need photos.  gpiozero uses Broadcom numbers for GPIO.  Hint 11/13/15 are not pin numbers.

Comment: Thank you joan, that was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that what needed to be done was to convert Broadcom numbers to GPIO numbers on the Raspberry Pi, as hinted in user joan's comment.

After following this mapping: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/checking-your-raspberry-pi-board-version/, the code needed to make the motor run was simply:

```
from gpiozero import Motor

motor1 = Motor(22, 27)

while True:
    motor1.forward()
```

Comment: https://pinout.xyz has an interactive diagram of the RPi.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the actual [gpiozero documentation for motor](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/recipes.html?highlight=robot#motors) clearer although [Robot](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/recipes.html?highlight=robot#robot) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3-pin controller board so you should initialize your [`Motor` class with enable pin](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/api_output.html#gpiozero.Motor), e.g. for Motor1:

```py
motor1 = Motor(forward=15, backward=13, enable=11)
```

Since you got the "Motorshield" you may want to have a look at its [documentation](https://shop.sb-components.co.uk/blogs/posts/controlling-dc-motor-using-raspberry-pi) and [`TestMotor.py` at their GitHub](https://github.com/sbcshop/MotorShield/blob/master/Test_Motor.py). It uses [`PyMotor.py` form the same repo](https://github.com/sbcshop/MotorShield/blob/master/PiMotor.py) as a "driver", so you may want to use it as an alternative.